# Reading JSON object: "TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file that has articles I obtained by using Webhose.io news article API. I cannot execute the API protocol again so I need to parse the individual articles in the JSON document: a sample of what it looks like is posted below.

JSON example

```
['{"thread": {"uuid": "6ed8101f1aa14181e3de43d064e3017be04ab8cb", "url": "https://m.dailyhunt.in/news/india/english/techquila-epaper-tecqla/amd+launches+new+radeon+rx+gpus+for+gaming+laptops+at+ces+2020-newsid-158539412", "site_full": "m.dailyhunt.in", "site": "dailyhunt.in", "site_section": "https://m.dailyhunt.in/news/india/english/science-topics-20", "site_categories": ["media"], "section_title": "", "title": "AMD Launches New Radeon RX GPUs For Gaming Laptops at CES 2020 - Techquila", "title_full": "AMD Launches New Radeon RX GPUs For Gaming Laptops at CES 2020 - Techquila | DailyHunt", "published": "2020-01-10T16:12:00.000+02:00", "replies_count": 0, "participants_count": 1, "site_type": "news", "country": "IN", "spam_score": 0.0, "main_image": "http://assets-news-bcdn.dailyhunt.in/cmd/resize/400x400_60/fetchdata15/images/d1/24/d0/d124d0bcedfd42cb5d29af215f5b6343.jpg", "performance_score": 0, "domain_rank": 14412, "social": {"facebook": {"likes": 0, "comments": 0, "shares": 0}, "gplus": {"shares": 0}, "pinterest": {"shares": 0}, "linkedin": {"shares": 0}, "stumbledupon": {"shares": 0}, "vk": {"shares": 0}}}, "uuid": "6ed8101f1aa14181e3de43d064e3017be04ab8cb", "url": "https://m.dailyhunt.in/news/india/english/techquila-epaper-tecqla/amd+launches+new+radeon+rx+gpus+for+gaming+laptops+at+ces+2020-newsid-158539412", "parent_url": null, "ord_in_thread": 0, "author": "TechQuila", "published": "2020-01-10T16:12:00.000+02:00", "title": "AMD Launches New Radeon RX GPUs For Gaming Laptops at CES 2020 - Techquila", "text": "At CES 2020, AMD...]
```

The script I am trying to execute is:

```
feeds = []
i = 0
for feed in output['posts']:
    feed['id'] = i
    print(feed['id'], str(feed['title']))
    i += 1
    feeds.append(feed)
```

Where I append the article titles to the empty "feeds" list.

Answer (score 1):

As per the json you have shared above, the element in the list is a string. So you need to convert that into a python dict first. You can make use of python's json module for that in the following manner:

```py
import json
feeds = []
i = 0
for feed in output['posts']:
    feed = json.loads(feed)
    feed['id'] = i
    print(feed['id'], str(feed['title']))
    i += 1
    feeds.append(feed)
```

Comment: I get the same error as before, the "object is not scriptable"

Comment: Can you share how you are populating the output variable from json file?

Comment: try changing it to json_data = json.load("name.json")

Comment: Its treating the file name as a string now: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: my bad, it should be `json_data = json.load(open("name.json"))`

Comment: It came back with this error now, and I think that it is because there are multiple lines per row in the document  "JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 5226)"

Comment: trying removing newline chars